# Por que este código não é responsivo?

Tags: bootstrap, layout-responsivo

Alguém pode me mostrar onde estou errando e meu código não se torna responsivo? (uso o bootstrap)

[image: Não ajusta com a tela pequena]

Queria que ficasse um elemento embaixo do outro...

Eis o código:

```
<div id='container'>
<div class='input-group'>
<span class='input-group-addon' id='basic-addon1' style='width: 110px;'>Escolha</span>
<select>
<option>Laranja</option><option>Goiaba</option><option>Banana</option>
</select>
<span class='label label-success'>Escolha uma fruta</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Não me recordo muito de todas classes do bootstrap, mas acho que falta adicionar as classes do grid system, além disso você colocou um `width: 110px;` isso faz com que o elemento fique fixo, tem certeza que esse código é o mesmo da imagem, parece faltar algumas coisas

Comment: Realmente... Esqueci de por a classe .selectpicker do meu SELECT. Quanto ao tamanho fixado, se eu não por ele fica bem maior que o label... Mas colocando as classes de grid, funcionou direitinho. Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Seu código possui alguns erros de construção, por isso não está responsivo.

A primeira coisa que notei é que você fixou o tamanho do `<span class="input-group-addon">`, isso ocasiona alguns problemas.

Outra coisa é que você não está definindo as *grids* para trabalhar seu *layout*.

Primeiro você deve definir uma `<div class="row">` para marcar a linha e dentro dela deve definir as colunas através das `<div class="col-lg-? col-md-? col-sm-? col-xs-?">` (Os `?` são apenas para representar o tamanho das colunas, que é variável).

Você também não colocou a classe `.form-control` no seu `<select>`.

Fiz alterações no seu código.

Veja se é dessa forma que está procurando:

```css
/* Esse padding é apenas p/ melhorar a visualização da resposta */
body {
  padding-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
      <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">Escolha</span>
        <select class="form-control">
          <option>Laranja</option><option>Goiaba</option><option>Banana</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
      <span class="label label-success">Escolha uma fruta</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Muitíssimo obrigado pela ajuda. Achei que não fosse necessário as classes de grid por se tratar de apenas uma linha... Mas coloquei e funcionou muito bem. Valeu mesmo!

Comment: Opa! Tamo junto, brother!

Comment: Paulo, sobre o tamanho fico do span... São 4 conjuntos de select um embaixo do outro. O label tem sempre o mesmo tamanho, mas as opções não. Daí fica desalinhado dependendo das opções que escolho em cada select...

Comment: Entendi. Por favor, edite a sua pergunta com seu código atualizado pra eu poder verificar.

Comment: Cara. O problema tá na classe que to usando: .selectpicker. Quando uso a que você sugeriu não tem nada disso. Não consegui editar. Vou responder com uma imagem só pra você entender melhor, mas já resolvi que vou deixar de usar a .selectpicker. Não é a primeira vez que me dá dor de cabeça... Mais uma vez, obrigado e boa noite.

Comment: Entendi. Isso acontece mesmo. Tranquilo, brother!

Answer (score 0):

É disso que estava falando...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O conjunto span + select tem tamanho fixo. Mas fica sambando na tela de acordo com a opção escolhida... Por isso queria fixar o span, mas quando tento fazer isso ele não responde adequadamente. As vezes fica até maior do que defino.